# basic cursor mysql with loop

Tags: mysql

I've been trying to create a cursor but for some reason i keep getting an error saying theres something wrong with the syntax.

what im asking is for a basic cursor that i can use with a loop so that i can call a function for each row. literally a mysql equivelent of php foreach loop

```
    function functionName ($commentId){
    $i = 0; 
    foreach (commentId as value) {
    //inside here we would do whatever function we would like but for this example i just want a basic increment to keep things simple and easy to understand
    $i++;
    } 
    echo $i;} 
    functionName(76);
```

i understand php is a little bit different as i would first need to select the rows using a mysql query and have the $commentId variable equal to the  but i was just using this as an example to make this question as clear as i can make it.

here is my example that keeps failing

```
    DELIMITER $$

    create function functionName(commentOn int(11)) returns int

    BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    declare var int;
    declare anotherVar int;
    set var = 0;
    set anotherVar = 0;

      DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT id FROM comments where `commentOnComment` = commentOn;
      DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

      OPEN cur1;

      read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH cur1 INTO anotherVar;

        set var = var + 1;

    IF done THEN
          LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;
      END LOOP;

      CLOSE cur1;

      return var;
    END; $$

    DELIMITER ;

    select functionName(76);
```

to explain what this example is in a little more detail, there is a table full of `comments`, the comment `id` and the id of the comment the user commented on (`commentOnComment`). and in the end i want to loop through all of the comments and select all where the `commentOnComment` equals the `id` of the comment the user commented on so that i can see how much replies each comment has i will change the increment to a `select count(*) from comments where commentOnComment = commentOn;` the commentOn parameter will be the id of the comment. **But for the answer shown for this question i just want an increment to keep it simple and easy for myself and other people to understand**.

Comment: The foreach arguments should be with `$` prefix I think.

Comment: Sorry im gonna remove the php tag, i just want someone to show me a basic mysql cursor inside a mysql function that will increment by one for each row. The php code was only put there to try and explain what i want as clearly as i could to people.

Comment: All declare statements must appear together after the begin statement and before any other code. And logically      set var = var + 1; should appear after the if done..endif test.

Comment: Thanks for the comment i got it working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to P.Salmon i was able to get a basic cursor with loop working, it was just the order of my code that was the problem. Im very greatfull as a little mistake like this would have taken me forever to figure out especially with the fact that i had never done a working cursor before.

here is the code for a basic cursor that does a function for each row in a table, in this example it increments the value of a variable by 1.

```
    DELIMITER $$

        create function functionName(commentOn int(11)) returns int

        BEGIN
        DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
        declare var int;
        declare anotherVar int;
        DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT id FROM comments where `commentOnComment` = commentOn;
          DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
        set var = 0;
        set anotherVar = 0;



          OPEN cur1;

          read_loop: LOOP
            FETCH cur1 INTO anotherVar;

        IF done THEN
              LEAVE read_loop;
            END IF;
    /*comment here is the area where you can add whatever insert, update, select or any 
      type of function you would like for each row. This is literally mysql's version of 
      php's foreach loop*/
            set var = var + 1;
          END LOOP;

          CLOSE cur1;

          return var;
        END; $$

        DELIMITER ;
```

as you can see its very similar to the question i just needed to change the order of my code. a simple `select functionName(id);` will give you the output, the `id` can be any number, in this example it would be the id of the row.

I am also curious as to why many people viewed this question but didnt answer, consequentially causing me to have to answer myself? if P.Salmon didnt comment and tell me the problem i would still be stuck. i tried to be as clear as i could, was it difficult to understand? was the question too hard for most people? feedback would be highly appreciated as it will help me in my future questions.